# Finding column header for the second highest value in a row of a dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a data frame:

```
Patch_0  Patch_1  Patch_2   Patch_7  exp_patch  
0        0.0      70.0      70.0       3            
1        0.0      70.0      74.0       4
```

using the following code I was able to find the colum header for the maximum value in that row:

```
df3['Highest_Rew_patch'] = df3.max(axis=1)
s = df3.iloc[:, df3.columns.str.startswith('Patch')].apply(lambda s:s.index[s.eq(s.max())].tolist(), axis=1)
s = s.apply(lambda s: ','.join(s))

Patch_0  Patch_1  Patch_2   Patch_7  exp_patch  Highest_Rew_patch
0        0.0      70.0      70.0       3            Patch_2,Patch_7
1        0.0      70.0      74.0       4            Patch_7
```

How do I create another new column with Second_highest and Third_highest values?
Desired output:

```
Patch_0     Patch_1    Patch_2   Patch_7   exp_patch     Highest_Rew_patch    Second_highest        
    0.0        0.0      70.0      70.0       3            Patch_2,Patch_7      Patch_0,Patch_1
    1.0        0.0      70.0      74.0       4            Patch_7              Patch_2
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get all ranks at once using [`rank`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.rank.html) and reshaping with [`melt`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.melt.html) and [`pivot_table`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.pivot_table.html):

```
df.join(df.filter(like='Patch')
   .rank(method='dense', ascending=False, axis=1)
   .astype(int)
   .reset_index()
   .melt('index')
   .pivot_table(index='index', columns='value', values='variable', aggfunc=','.join)
 .iloc[:,:3] # optional: keep only top 3
 )
```

Output:

```
   Patch_0  Patch_1  Patch_2  Patch_7  exp_patch                1                2        3
0        0      0.0     70.0     70.0          3  Patch_2,Patch_7  Patch_0,Patch_1      NaN
1        1      0.0     70.0     74.0          4          Patch_7          Patch_2  Patch_0
```

Answer (score 1):

Keep your code, but instead of `s.max()`, use `s.nlargest(2)[-1]`.

Comment: worked for most of the random checks that i did in the dataframe however some rows still yielded wrong values in the second highest column. Could you help what wud have gone wrong here ?

Answer (score 1):

one step for all rank

```
s = pd.wide_to_long(df.reset_index(),['Patch'],i = 'index',j='a',suffix='\\w+',sep='_').reset_index()
s['new'] = s.groupby('index')['Patch'].rank('dense')

out = df.join(pd.crosstab(index=s['index'],columns = s['new'], values= s['a'].astype(str).radd('Patch'),aggfunc=','.join))
```